# Nodejs saving to mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to save data to database but i dont know how to do it in this case.

userModel.js

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    unique: true
  },
  password: String,
  passwordResetToken: String,
  passwordResetExpires: Date,

  profile: {
    firstname: String,
    lastname: String,
    gender: String,
    status: String,
    location: String,
    website: String,
    picture: String
  }
});
```

Signup.js

```
 const user = new User({
    firstname: req.body.firstname,
    lastname: req.body.lastname,
    location: req.body.location,
    status: 0,
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password
  });
```

Problem is that those things in profile wont save and i dont know how to edit that signup.js to make it work. Something like `profile.firstname: req.body.firstname` does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const user = new User({
    profile: {
        firstname: req.body.firstname,
        lastname: req.body.lastname,
        location: req.body.location,
        status: 0,
    },
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password
});
```

From schema (`userModel.js`), we need update with `profile` structure

Answer (score 0):

You need to save like this in `signUp.js`

```
const user = new User({
    profile :{
        firstname: req.body.firstname,
        lastname: req.body.lastname,
        location: req.body.location,
        status: 0
    },
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password
  });
```

As `firstname`, `lastname`, `location` and `status` are part of the `profile` object.